# Why can't one iterate through enum data within a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, enums

Say I have some enum, `Channel`, filled with sample property data:

```
enum Channel: CaseIterable {
  case abc
  case efg
  case hij
  
  var name: String {
    switch self {
    case .abc:  return "ABC"
    case .efg:  return "EFG"
    case .hij:  return "HIJ"
    }
  }
}

extension Channel: Identifiable {
  var id: Self { self }
}
```

And some view implementation to fill said content with:

```
struct ChannelHome: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(Channel.allCases) { channel in
        NavigationLink(destination: ChannelDetail(channel)) {
          Text(channel.name)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}   // big closure yikes
```

Why doesn't this work? Is this due to the nature of enums not having static properties and SwiftUI being declarative? Are there ways around this? Such as:

```
struct ChannelData {
  static let channels: [Channel] = [.abc, .efg, .hij]
  // or
  static func getChannels() -> [Channel] {
    var channelArray: [Channel]
    for channel in Channel.allCases {
      channelArray.append(channel)
    }
    return channelArray
  }
}
```

Or, *more* preferably, are there better practices for presenting small data sets like these in a SwiftUI view? I like being able to implement a visual UI of my properties for when I'm debugging, as a whole, at runtime (closer to the production stage).

I apologies in advance for the question, I am just getting into it with SwiftUI.

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? All seems works fine here (Xcode 13 / iOS 15). Maybe you just forgotten to wrap `ChannelHome`'s content into `NavigationView` to make links working?

Comment: You code works for me in Xcode 13 on an iOS 15 simulator. It displays the the letters on the screen. (I removed the NavigationLink as you didn't provide `ChannelDetail`)

Comment: By the  way, your `getChannels` method doesn't actually do anything, at all.

Answer (score 26):

Here are 2 simple ways for you, but not sure where can be helpful for you because with enum you cannot update ForEach elements, but it has a use case for showing data!

First way without any Identifiable id:

```
struct ContentView: View {        
    var body: some View {            
        ForEach(TestEnum.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in                 
            Text(item.rawValue)                
        }
    }        
}

enum TestEnum: String, CaseIterable { case a, b, c }
```

with Identifiable id that conforms to Identifiable protocol, you can cut `, id: \.id` even:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(TestEnum.allCases, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

enum TestEnum: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable { case a, b, c
    var id: String { return self.rawValue }
}
```

Comment: This is oddly double spaced, is that intentional?

Comment: Space! The question is not about space! It is about enum and ForEach! Take the idea about those!

Comment: That's fine, but the formatting is weird.

Comment: Forget format! The idea is important

Comment: "Forget format!" No thanks. It's how you communicate ideas, which is usually where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I don't think you read anything I said. I'm disengaging now.

Comment: You can also do `id: \.self` and then `item.rawValue`

Answer (score 9):

Either Xcode was getting hung up on cache errors or I am a fool (probably the latter). Regardless, the issue seems to have been resolved with the following Identifiable extension to your enum, as well as a good ol' derived data purge and clean:

```
extension Channel: Identifiable {
  var id: Self { self }
}
```

I seem to have confused this issue with another long-time issue that I've constantly run into; mostly regarding enums and their distaste for storing static data (as is simply just the nature of their fast and lite structure).