# if Array is empty, append all values in enum to array

Tags: ios, swiftui

First Dabble in SwiftUI, I've managed to get the below code working such that when I press a button, it will show a "selected" state and add the selected sports into an array. (and remove from the array if "deselected")

However, I can't figure out how to initialise the sportsArray with ALL values within the enum `HelperIntervalsIcu.icuActivityType.allCases` if it is initially empty.

I tried to put in

```
if sportsArray.isEmpty {
  HelperIntervalsIcu.icuActivityType.allCases.forEach {
  sportsArray.append($0.rawvalue)
}
```

but Xcode keeps telling me `type() cannot conform to View` or things along those lines

```
struct selectSports: View {
  @State private var sportsArray = [String]()
   
  var body: some View {

    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
      HStack {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/69455949/14414215
        ForEach(Array(HelperIntervalsIcu.icuActivityType.allCases), id:\.rawValue) { sport in
          Button(action: {
            addSports(sport: sport.rawValue)
          }) {
            HStack {
              Image(getSportsIcon(sport: sport.rawValue))
                .selectedSportsImageStyle(sportsArray: sportsArray, sport: sport.rawValue)
              Text(sport.rawValue)
            }
          }
          .buttonStyle(SelectedSportButtonStyle(sportsArray: sportsArray, sport: sport.rawValue))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  
  struct SelectedSportButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var sportsArray: [String]
    var sport: String
    
    var selectedSport : Bool {
      if sportsArray.contains(sport) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
      configuration.label
        .font(selectedSport ? Font.subheadline.bold() : Font.subheadline)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .foregroundColor(selectedSport ? Color.orange : Color(UIColor.label))
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 15)
        .padding([.top, .bottom],10)
        .overlay(
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
            .foregroundColor(selectedSport ? Color.orange : Color.gray)
        )
        .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
    }
  }
  
  func addSports(sport: String) {
    if sportsArray.contains(sport) {
      let sportsIndex = sportsArray.firstIndex(where: { $0 == sport })
      sportsArray.remove(at: sportsIndex!)
    } else {
      sportsArray.append(sport)
    }
    print("Selected Sports:\(sportsArray)")
  }
}
```

No Sports Selected (in this case sportsArray is empty and thus the default state which I would like have would be to have ALL sports Pre-selected)
[image]

2 Sports Selected

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted to do that in `onAppear`, like

```
struct selectSports: View {
  @State private var sportsArray = [String]()
   
  var body: some View {

    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
       // .. other code
    }
    .onAppear {
       if sportsArray.isEmpty {    // << here !!
          HelperIntervalsIcu.icuActivityType.allCases.forEach {
             sportsArray.append($0.rawvalue)
          }
       } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: onAppear and onDisappear is the equivalent of UIKit's viewWillAppear which was exactly what I wanted/needed.